# How to check that the response email body contains some keyword and write logic based on the key words?

Tags: apex, emailmessage

We need to write some logic to update the case fields based on the email response we get . and we need to omit some key words from the email response. I have writted below logic to avoid some keywords (like OOO, Auto reply .. ) in the logic i have specified capital 'OOO' , but if i send the response with small 'ooo' it is not capturing. But i want the logic should capture all the keyword with upper and lower. Below is the code i have written. Can any one help me how to make the logic case insensitive.

```
public static void caseAccuracyCalculation(List<EmailMessage> emailList){
    DateTime dt;

    for(EmailMessage em : emailList){
        if(em.Incoming == true){
         list<Case> listCase = [Select id,status,RCA_Closed_Date__c,recordType.Name FROM Case where id=: em.ParentId];
            for(Case c: listCase){
                if(c.status == 'Resolved'){
                    dt = c.RCA_Closed_Date__c +5;            
                    system.debug('dt::' +dt +'c.RCA_Closed_Date__c:::' +c.RCA_Closed_Date__c + 'c.recordType.Name:::' +c.recordType.Name);
                    if(c.recordType.Name != 'AMS' || c.recordType.Name != 'Claim Management' || c.recordType.Name != 'Project Management' || c.recordType.Name != 'Location/Incident Management' || c.recordType.Name != 'Workspace Management')
                    {
                        system.debug('c.recordType.Name::' +c.recordType.Name);

                        if(!em.TextBody.contains('OOO') && !em.TextBody.contains('Out Of Office') && !em.TextBody.contains('Automatic Reply') && !em.TextBody.contains('Undeliverable') && !em.TextBody.contains('Auto Reply') && !em.TextBody.contains('Respuesta de Estoy ausente') && !em.TextBody.contains('自动答复') && !em.TextBody.contains('自動回覆') && !em.TextBody.contains('不在回覆') && !em.TextBody.contains('不在辦公室') && !em.TextBody.contains('自動応答')&& c.RCA_Closed_Date__c !=null)
                        {                                        
                            c.status='Reopened';
                            c.Case_Accuracy_SLA__c = 'False';
                            system.debug('c.Case_Accuracy_SLA__c::' +c.Case_Accuracy_SLA__c +'c.id::' +c.id +'em.ParentId:' +em.ParentId);                               

                        }

                    }
                }

                Update c;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use "containsIgnoreCase" instead of "contains"; the former is case-insensitive, while the latter is not. Alternatively, you might look at writing a [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) to simplify your code with a regular expression.